# Create a CosmosDB connection whitout using the "createIfNotExists"

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using nodeJS and I'm trying to create a connection with the CosmosDB, I would like to know if I can do that without the use of "createIfNotExists"

```
const getCosmosClient = async (): Promise<Database> => {
  const { database } = await cosmosClient.databases.createIfNotExists({ id: DATABASES.databaseId });

  return database;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glancing at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/cosmosclient?view=azure-node-latest#database_string_), you can use `cosmosClient.database(id)`. It should return a `Database` instead of a `Promise<DatabaseResponse>`.